# How do I add a picture to a contact?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I tried to add a picture to a contact, but I do not know how.

Comment: You have to tell us where you want to add a contact! thunderbird? pidgin? Or should we guess?

Answer (score 3):

You are probably trying to do it from the website. It hasn't been implemented yet, I've filed a bug so we make sure it's on our list of things to get done: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-servers/+bug/770469